# Is there a one-liner to read in a file to a string in C++?

Tags: c++, file, filesystems

I need a quick easy way to get a string from a file in standard C++.  I can write my own, but just want to know if there is already a standard way, in C++.

Equivalent of this if you know Cocoa:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file];
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We can do it but it's a long line :

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // The one-liner
    string fileContents(istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifstream("filename.txt")), istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    // Check result
    cout << fileContents;
}
```

Edited : use "istreambuf_iterator" instead of "istream_iterator"

Comment: You just used the ',' operator, its essentially just like putting a bunch of statements with a semicolon between them on one line. But even with that, it beats mine below by a line, nice.

Comment: If you use an istreambuf_iterator (see Martin York's comment on my post) you can forget the noskipws.

Comment: Another comment, ifstream is a temporary, can you ensure it won't close while we still have istream_iterators to it? Would the evaluation of this be compiler specific.

Comment: @Doug T : I don't use the ',' operator. Read the code again. I only use the string constructor with two parameters.

Comment: @Doug T : Temporary Objects are destroyed after the evaluation of the full-expression that is just before the semi-colon.

Comment: Nice! Just a note: I think this will fail silently (give you an empty string) if the file doesn't exist. To deal with that you need to check the ifstream's .fail().

Comment: I'm not sure that labelling one of the many lines "one-liner" makes it so :-D

Comment: Unfortunately as is I couldn't get this to work as is in JNI C++ call. In case someone stumbles across this gem of an error (soo many braces)
error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}' to 'std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >::streambuf_type* {aka std::basic_streambuf<char>*} (Using NDK 9de, APP_STL := gnustl_static)

Answer (score 11):

Its almost possible with an istream_iterator (3 lines!)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file("filename.txt");
    string fileContents;

    copy(istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
              istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
              back_inserter(fileContents));
}
```

Edited - got rid of intermediate string stream, now copies straight into the string, and now using istreambuf_iterator, which ignores whitespace (thanks Martin York for your comment).

Comment: Put that in its own function and now you've got a one-liner. Just call that function.

Comment: Why not use istreambuf_iterator<char>(). It does not skip white space.

Comment: @Martin York - thanks, I was actually trying to search for that, but couldn't think of it.

Answer (score 4):

The standard C++ library doesn't provide a function to do this.

Comment: Best answer. Sure, it CAN be done, but it's a mess. Much better to accept it isn't there and write your own. A single function call will definitely be a one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

Best I can do is 5 lines:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

ifstream f("filename.txt");
f.seekg(0, ios::end);
vector<char> buffer(f.tellg());
f.seekg(0, ios::beg);
f.read(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
```

Comment: Is the f.seekg() trick always correct about the length of the file?  What about CRLF conversion on Windows?

Comment: I guess you could open the file in binary mode so it's not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( void )
{
  stringstream os(stringstream::out);
  os << ifstream("filename.txt").rdbuf();
  string s(os.str());
  cout << s << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do it like the following (but properly wrapped up nicely unlike below), you can read in the file without worrying about a 0x1A byte in the file (for example) cutting the reading of the file short. The previously suggested methods will choke on a 0x1A (for example) in a file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    FILE* in = fopen("filename.txt", "rb");
    if (in == NULL) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (fseek(in, 0, SEEK_END) != 0) {
        fclose(in);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    const long filesize = ftell(in);
    if (filesize == -1) {
        fclose(in);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    vector<unsigned char> buffer(filesize);
    if (fseek(in, 0, SEEK_SET) != 0 || fread(&buffer[0], sizeof(buffer[0]), buffer.size(), in) != buffer.size() || ferror(in) != 0) {
        fclose(in);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fclose(in);
}
```

But, yeh, it's not an already-implemented 1-liner though.

Edit: 0x1A wasn't a good example as ios_base::binary will cover that. However, even then C++ streams often give me trouble when reading in png files all at once with .read(). Using the C way works better. Just can't remember a good example to show why. It was probably with .read()ing a binary file in blocks in a loop instead that can be a problem with C++ streams. So, disregard this post.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string temp, file; std::ifstream if(filename); while(getline(if, temp)) file += temp;
```

It's not a short or single-statement line, but it is one line and it's really not that bad.